# How to trigger channel broadcast in the controller in Phoenix

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I'm trying to figure out on how to **trigger** the channel **broadcast** from the controller.

**Example**

```
def create(conn, %{"message" => message_params}) do
with {:ok, %Message{} = message} <- Chat.create_message(message_params) do
  conn

  # TRIGGER CHANNEL BROADCAST "SHOUT" HERE

  |> put_status(:created)
  |> put_resp_header("location", message_path(conn, :show, message))
  |> render("show.json", message: message)
end end
```

**water_cooler channel**

```
defmodule NotificationWeb.WaterCoolerChannel do
 use NotificationWeb, :channel
 def join("water_cooler:lobby", _payload, socket) do
  {:ok, socket}
 end
 def handle_in("shout", payload, socket) do
 broadcast socket, "shout", payload
  {:noreply, socket}
 end
end
```

I've tried to use `NotificationWeb.broadcast(topic, event, msg)` but confused on what to put in

**topic = "water_cooler" ?**

**event = ?**

**message = ?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to broadcast a message using [broadcast](https://hexdocs.pm/phoenix/Phoenix.Endpoint.html#c:broadcast/3) function of the `NotificationWeb.Endpoint`.

- `topic` here is the room, in which you want to broadcast (for example `water_cooler:lobby`)
- `event` is the name of the event, you're expecting to receive on the client
- `msg` is the additional information within the event

Considering you have something like this on the front-end part:

```
channel.on("new_msg", payload => {
  // process new message
})
```

then `event` equals `new_msg`, and `msg` is the data, which `payload` variable within this event will contain